# Wireless down in dual boot of Ubuntu, but works on Windows side

Tags: wireless

My battery ran completely out yesterday while I was working on my lappy. I plugged it in to a power source but my internet connection will not take hold now. The wireless router is working, and shows up. But I get repeated requests from Ubuntu to enter the key, etc.

The laptop is a dual boot, with the problem being in the Ubuntu partition, which is why I am working at the moment from the Windows side, where I can access that same router, and post this plea for help.

I have rebooted the router and modem. No dice. And, I deleted the connection from the Network Manager, and re-added it. Still no internet in Ubuntu. Someone had posted a note about the DPCH being stuck - to go into the terminal and restart the network services from there. But, they did not provide the correct command sequence. Any help?  Please?

Comment: What **Ubuntu** version?  I guess you mean **DHCP** being stick.  What brand/model of laptop?  What brand.model of WiFi (built-in/dongle)?

Answer (score 1):

After resuming from hibernation I could not reconnect to the same SSID however I was able to connect to other SSID in the area. I tried reseting the configs on my PC and changing the the wlan0 up and down. THen I decided to try the router anyways after trial and error I decided to change the broadcast channel from Auto to 3 and then my laptop connected.

i dont know why it worked but try changing the broadcast channel from the router. good luck